# Botium - How to get bot message in botium-bindings

Tags: botium-box

I am running botium test for Google Dialogflow using Mocha as a test runner. Due to some reporting requirements, I forked botium-binding, but I am unable to retrieve the bot message.

Are there any hooks to retrieve the bot message while the test runs?

I am aware of the below construct, but it doesn't look like this code is called while Mocha runs the test.

```
WaitBotSays (...args) {
    if (this.container) {
        return this.container.WaitBotSays(...args)
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Botium Initialization failed. Please see error messages above (enable debug logging).'))
    }
}
```

I also tried to call WaitBotSays from this.compiler.convos.forEach((convo) => {...} but it seems to wait for the bot to respond and not proceed with the next step in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way to do this without forking.

You could add your own **Logic Hook** to Botium to intercept the bot responses, see [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/tree/master/samples/extensions/logichooks) for a sample. Or [this one](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-logichook-perfectoreporting). Also there is a sample in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24477705/Developing+Custom+Asserters).

Or you could inject your own logic with the [custom hooks interface](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#Custom-Hooks).

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and get back with my findings. I do have custom asserters that use the bot message, but didn't find a way to export it to out for reporting. The perfecto example looks like what I need to do.